# Will DevExpress require to be installed on local machine?

Tags: c#, devexpress

I have installed DevExpress on my own computer. And I used it in a C# project for showing records.

Will it be required to be installed on the client machine?

Datagridview layout for images with text not looking so good.

Answer (score 4):

No, an installation is not needed on the client machine, but the assemblies you are using have to be *deployed* alongside your app. That won't cost anything for your client as long as you as a developer have a valid license:

From [the FAQ](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/licensingfaq.xml)

> Developer Express does not charge any royalties for redistribution of components that have been integrated into applications which you engineer. Of course, this only applies if you have a valid license to all products which are being used within your application.

For deployment scenario's take a look [here](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/15031/Build-an-Application/Redistribution-and-Deployment):

> When you deploy a WinForms project that uses DevExpress WinForms controls, you should copy the corresponding assembly files onto an end-user machine.

Basically this means you can copy the entire bin folder of your app (web, wpf, winforms or else) that include the used DevExpress assemblies and put in on any client.

Comment: what if i crack install devexpress

Comment: To do what? You have no license at all? Anyway, this site is not here for discussion about illegal use. And as stated, you *do not* need a license for deployments to client systems of your app. Only for developers.

Comment: Additionally, the [DevExpress Assembly Deployment Tool](https://documentation.devexpress.com/AssemblyDeploymentTool/17237/Assembly-Deployment-Tool) can be used to collect the references required for distribution of your program. Some of the DevExpress libraries are loaded dynamically at runtime, so you may miss out on them without the use of the tool to scan your solution.